# source of tcpdump outgoing requests

Tags: tcpdump

I ran the following command:

```
sudo tcpdump 'port 80' and src host 172.31.0.198 -w /tmp/http.log
```

This should have started tracking my outgoing activity on port 80 as that is my local address, then sent it to http.log. Now I want to analyze that activity to determine where outbound requests are coming from, what processes, files or users are sending the requests. However, I tried viewing the file in vim and I am getting a bunch of random characters.

What do the characters mean, and how can I view where the outgoing http requests are coming from?

See image below:

[image]

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/38626/how-can-i-read-pcap-files-in-a-friendly-format and http://openmaniak.com/tcpdump.php

Comment: tl:dr `tcpdump -r /tmp/http.log`

Comment: Also, by definition, outound requests are coming from you ;p

Comment: lol thanks, I meant like a file or process or something that was making the requests. I will take a look at the links you sent.

Comment: you may prefer other tools, lsof or netstat `lsof -i -n -P` , `netstat -ntulp` sort of depends on what exactly you are looking for. My guess is that you do not need the raw packets (tcpdump) but I am not sure.

Comment: well, my ultimate goal is, I am not sure if the outgoing requests are legitimately from something I setup or not. and so if I can track which file or process they are coming from I will be able to research it more.

Comment: snort can help as snort filters all the packets and brings suspicious traffic to your attention.

Answer (score 0):

use linux I/O redirection, standard operator **>**

**sudo tcpdump 'port 80' and src host 192.168.1.4 > /tmp/http.log
cat /tmp/http.log**

you should mention your source address in place of "192.168.1.4"